# How to use Entity Framework in DotNetNuke7?

Tags: module, dotnetnuke-7

I want to use Entity Framework  for make Module in DotNetNuke7.I search on the internet but don't exist Helpful document in this case.
Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice little tutorial at DNNCreative.com.  You have to subscribe to the site, though.

I don't recall, off the top of my head, whether there are similar tutorials at DNNHero.com, also a subscription site.

Answer (score 0):

I sew DNNHero.com site .In this site exist a video tutorial  for in this case but it is premium . In my country we don't access to Paypal , ... account for payment . At the result I can not use this tutorial. In DNNCreative.com have a little tutorial I use it but it is not complete tutorial and I have a problem  that you see in this [LINK](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CDYQFjADahUKEwjCk865_JvJAhWBuhoKHbaNCvI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F33417859%2Fhow-to-change-module-build-file-for-use-ef-in-dnn-7&usg=AFQjCNEbZRIOVe8sFBkbBHbnzCiRdlEm9w&sig2=JA4grdQg18V2pSFRHUkHOQ)